# How to create an executable in Ubuntu of a c program

Tags: c, ubuntu

I would like to create an executable of my two  mycode.c and my main.c, how can I create an executable? i did

gcc mycode.c main.c

and it generates a a.out, but when i click it it would not run.. (i am new to this so please bear with me)

Thank you

Comment: Try `./a.out` on the commandline.

Comment: ^ Yes. Also look into Makefiles for making several different executables or when you have several interlinking dependencies. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6x0EHAzCJc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
gcc mycode.c main.c -o myprogram
```

Then run `./myprogram`

If you double click it you probably won't see anything, you should instead try running it from the command line, where you compiled it from in the first place.

Comment: Run using ./myprogram, not myprogram (from the directory you saved it in - I know you know that, Alex, just as he's confused)

Answer (score 0):

Your a.out might not be executable yet.
do:
`$> chmod 755 a.out`
or
`$> chmod a+x a.out`
then try running it:
`$> ./a.out`

Comment: Not likely; gcc gives `a.out` execute permission.  If you double-click an `a.out’ file (probably from Nautilus), it should execute it, but not in a terminal.